# adding scriptdoing problem at admin side

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-1.3

i got a add from goolge . when i place it at my user side it wrok well , i want that script show on my admin side i want just script code , 
but now whn i fetch adds from data base , there are shown as a add not as a scrpit ..
anu idea .. i am using this in php,
i have come to shoe some htmlentity function is user for ds if i dng this type of coding how a i manage it ..

$show ='
       '.$row[add_code].'
       ';
hoe to use htmlentity function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of [htmlentities](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php), which converts all characters that have a matching HTML character entity, using [htmlspecialchars](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) should suffice. `htmlspecialchars` only replaces `" ' < > &`, so no markup in the string will be interpreted.

You just pass it your code and it returns a string with those characters converted.

```
$show = htmlspecialchars(' '.$row[add_code].' ');
```

`htmlentities` works the same.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to show the advert on the public pages, but the script for the advert on the admin pages?

Why not use a conditional to surround it with `<pre>...</pre>` then you won't need to convert any entities and you'll be able to inspect the code as it really is.